# Data.Dataset1.refresh() method does not work in the Smartcafe

Tags: smartface.io

After inserting some values to a dataset which is binded to a repeatbox I have used refresh() method but I could not any changes in the repeatbox.

I can only see the changes when the page is load again.

```
Data.Dataset1.add();
Data.Dataset1.Name = "deneme";
Data.Dataset1.commit();
Data.Dataset1.refresh();
```

There is any mistake in my codes?

Comment: I tried to use this code in the onShow event of page, it adds the line deneme to repeatbox. Which device do you use?

Comment: Name property may cause the problem because "name" is a special wording.

Comment: The word "Name" is not a  reserved word, so it can be used. The reserved one is "name" that is written with lowercase "n".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Data.notify("Data.Dataset1");`

Try this:

```
Data.Dataset1.add();
Data.Dataset1.Name = "deneme";
Data.Dataset1.commit();
Data.notify("Data.Dataset1");
```